# Binary to Hexadecimal number

Tags: binary

I know how to convert `0101 | 0111` 
in which the `0101` gives me `5`, and `0111` gives me `7`
So hexadecimal number is: `57`

But how about `0011 | 1100`
`0011` gives me `3`, but `1100` gives me `12`, does it mean the hexadecimal number is `312`?

Thanks!

Comment: No, $3C$, recall hex $A, B, C, D, E, F for 10$ through $15$. Regards

Comment: ...and $12$ in decimal is *C* in hexa... :-)

Answer (score 1):

In hexadecimal you need 16 digits. This is usually achieved by using $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F$. That is $F$ is fifteen and $10$ is sixteen.

When converting from binary to hexadecimal, each group of four binary digits becomes one hexadecimal digit. In the case you are asking, $1100_2$ corresponds to $C_{16}$.